# Cascading Parameter

Tags: reporting-services

In SSRS reporting, I have three parameters as mentioned below,

1. Period
2. Start date
3. End date

My scenario is,

"Period" parameter has four values:

1. Quarterly
2. Monthly
3. Weekly
4. Adhoc

For example if user runs report for this month:

1. when user select "Quarterly" values passed to other two parameters will be 01/04/2019 and 30/06/2017
2. when user select "Monthly" values passed to other two parameters will be 01/06/2019 and 30/06/2017
3. when user select "Weekly" values passed to other two parameters will be 01/07/2019 and 07/07/2017
4. when user select "Adhoc" , the parameter should accepts values from the user.

For quarterly, monthly and weekly default values should be passed to "Start Date" and "End date"

Comment: Hi, Could you try to clarify your question? I'm struggling to understand what your need help with

Comment: Hi,I am a newbie. I don't know how to proceed with this scenario. If i pass Quarterly,Monthly and weekly value as a default to start date and end date , for adhoc I couldn't enter a value.